# JApplet - add menu & Paint component

Tags: java, menu, applet, paint, japplet

I am trying to do very simple application with JApplet , on top I need one menu bar and below that menu , I just use paint components which I draw some line or some string or shape .

The sample code for my application is below , but if you run this code you will see the menu will be covert by paint stage unless you click on the menu bar area . I search in google , but I could not find match solution for it .

If anyone can suggest me what is the correct root for it , I will be thankful .

```
public class MyApplication extends JApplet {

    public void init() {
        setSize(400, 400);
         this.setBackground(new Color(0x646060));

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu menuOption = new JMenu("Options");
        JMenuItem Camera01 = new JMenuItem("Camera 01", 1);
        menuOption.add(Camera01);
        menubar.add(menuOption);
        setJMenuBar(menubar);
    }

   public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"I am trying to do very simple application with JApplet"* Whenever applets are involved, expect 'complicated'.  Why are you trying to code an applet as opposed to launching a `JFrame` from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  While it is clear (to me) what the rendering problem is, I think we should get these other matters sorted before we get to that.